# In SQL how to compare date values?

Tags: sql, mysql, compare, where-clause

Using MySQL syntax and having a table with a row like:

```
mydate DATETIME NULL,
```

Is there a way to do something like:

```
... WHERE mydate<='2008-11-25';
```

I'm trying but not really getting it to work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Nevermind found an answer. Ty the same for anyone who was willing to reply.

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(mydata,'2008-11-20') >=0;
```

Comment: This looks slow:  function call and implicit conversion for every row in the table.  There must be a way to compare dates more directly.

Answer (score 27):

Uh, `WHERE mydate<='2008-11-25'` *is* the way to do it. That should work.

Do you get an error message? Are you using an ancient version of MySQL?

Edit: The following works fine for me on MySQL 5.x

```
create temporary table foo(d datetime);
insert into foo(d) VALUES ('2000-01-01');
insert into foo(d) VALUES ('2001-01-01');
select * from foo where d <= '2000-06-01';
```

Comment: On my PostgreSQL DBMS, indeed, it works fine. May be a MySQL weakness?

Comment: Err, it does too work on MySQL. :) I just tried it to make sure I'm not nuts.

What version of MySQL you using fmfs? Do you get an error?

Answer (score 13):

In standard SQL syntax, you would use:

```
WHERE mydate <= DATE '2008-11-20'
```

That is, the keyword DATE should precede the string.  In some DBMS, however, you don't need to be that explicit; the system will convert the DATE column into a string, or the string into a DATE value, automatically.  There are nominally some interesting implications if the DATE is converted into a string - if you happen to have dates in the first millennium (0001-01-01 .. 0999-12-31) and the leading zero(es) are omitted by the formatting system.

Comment: Note that, if all the dates are in the ISO 8601 format as shown, string comparisons will work (it is a feature of ISO 8601).

Comment: If the leading zeroes are included, yes.  In theory, if you have dates prior to 1000-01-01, the DBMS might omit leading zeroes.  I'm not sure it is very likely, but funnier things have been known.  Oracle supports dates BCE (BC); those do not compare reliably as strings.

Answer (score 3):

You could add the time component

```
WHERE mydate<='2008-11-25 23:59:59'
```

but that might fail on DST switchover dates if mydate is '2008-11-25 24:59:59', so it's probably safest to grab everything before the next date:

```
WHERE mydate < '2008-11-26 00:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be that you are dealing with DATETIME data, not just dates. If a row has a mydate that is '2008-11-25 09:30 AM', then your *WHERE mydate<='2008-11-25';* is not going to return that row.  '2008-11-25' has an implied time of 00:00 (midnight), so even though the date part is the same, they are not equal, and mydate is larger.

If you use < '2008-11-26' instead of <= '2008-11-25', that would work. The Datediff method  works because it compares just the date portion, and ignores the times.